# Send all not set domains (and subdomains) to another folder

Tags: apache, subdomain, vhosts

The problem i have is  that when i didn't set the domain, it doesent changes the documentroot to a blank one (e.g. http://lol.orbitrondev.org), (see code to see what i mean)

```
# File 001-sites.conf
<VirtualHost _default_:*>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/sites/blank
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory "/var/www/sites/blank">
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

instead it sends everything to my admin site, but i dont know why. My admin file is like this:

```
# File 002-admin.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName admin.orbitrondev.org:80
    ServerAdmin team-orbitron@hotmail.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/admin
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory "/var/www/admin">
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I also have many other vhosts set but they all look like the above one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the answer but since I changed `<VirtualHost _default_:*>` to this `<VirtualHost _default_:80>` it works. But it's not the solution if I want that ALL PORTS also give this blank page